# phpredis returns "Couldn't map cluster keyspace using any provided seed" error

Tags: php, phpredis, elastic-cache

phpredis returns "Couldn't map cluster keyspace using any provided seed" error when trying to connect to **AWS ElasticCache for Redis cluster with tls/ssl turned on**.

*Everything is working fine if the AWS ElasticCache for Redis cluster has no tls/ssl turned on*.

I am running my code in an EC2 within same vpc and subnet like the Redis-cluster.

Here is my connection code from php

```
$this -> redis = new RedisCluster(null, Array('tls://url1.10j6zb.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379','tls://url2.10j6zb.aps1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'));
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

*Apologies, this is not a reply specifically about TLS*

I ran into this myself under PHP REDIS 2.2.8 on PHP 5.6 and I could reproduce when basically making a **cluster in AWS with a single shard**, as soon as I added two shards the issue went away. I could also re-create this using a single redis node in cluster mode, with itself as its only node.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
redis_cluster_of_one:
  container_name: redis_cluster_of_one
  image: bitnami/redis-cluster:latest
  environment:
    ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
    REDIS_NODES: "redis_cluster_of_one"
    REDIS_CLUSTER_CREATOR: "yes"
    REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS: "1"
  ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  volumes:
    - redis_cluster_of_one:/bitnami

volumes:
  redis_cluster_of_one:
    driver: local
```

I had already been testing locally with a cluster of six, but the single sharded AWS cluster failed me.